# How do I fix the Invalid Next control variable reference

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a summary worksheet that pulls source data from standardized worksheets into one consolidating page in a separate workbook. I am very new to VBA so I have pulled some stuff from around the web and added a few things in myself.  My problem now is that I am getting the "Invalid Next Control Variable" error near the bottom of the code at the "Next Workbook" point.

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Workbook As Workbook
Dim rng As Range
rng = ("a1:a10")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Filename = "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\Consolidating Macro"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")
Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 For Each rng In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Update")
 rng.Copy
 Workbook("Testing").Select
 Sheets("Tracker").Select
 Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
 rng.Paste
 Next Workbook
 Workbooks(Filename).Close
 Filename = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried referencing worksheets and workbooks but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix this error? I have been looking around for a while now and can't find another way to reference the next workbook in the loop. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you even using For Loop ? You defined `rng = "A1:A10"` ,  and there can be only one range in every sheet. So you can directly refer to it, no need for a for loop.

Comment: There are lot of things wrong with your code but to answer your question, you are using the `For` loop for a `Range` but your `Next` is referring to a `Workbook`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mikku 
I was under the impression I had to use a loop to tell the code to repeat the process for every workbook in the folder. Will it do this without the loop as long as I specify the folder?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thank you for your comment! This get me through that error, now on to the next one :)